# Web app: points-based task pledging and tracking

Tags: web-apps

I am a member of a social organization and run its website. We will be starting a campaign in a couple of weeks to challenge members to pledge to accomplish certain points-based tasks, and want to track the pledges, completions, and rolled-up sums on a web-based application.

1. There are roughly 100 tasks, with different point values and descriptions. Tasks are individual: more than one member can pledge to do a task.
2. A member would sign up on a per-user page to complete certain tasks. The sums of a member's pledged tasks and completed tasks should be displayed on the per-user page, and there should be a summary of all members' pledged and completed points and tasks available as well.
3. A member needs to be able to return to his/her page to update pledges and completions.

A simple example:

```
Member: J. Jones

 TASK    POINTS
Task A    50    [X] No    [ ] Pledged    [ ] Completed
Task B    30    [ ] No    [X] Pledged    [ ] Completed
Task C    80    [ ] No    [ ] Pledged    [X] Completed
Task D    10    [ ] No    [ ] Pledged    [X] Completed

Totals                    Pledged: 30    Completed: 90
                                  Both: 120
```

Do you have suggestions for a self-hosted or third-party web-based service that would do this? I have found task-management and to-do list sites and software, but none with points tracking. Some kind of voting or survey site might work too, but the user has to be able to return to update the votes/survey.